# Совершенный вид глагола или совершённый?

Tags: фонетика, этимология

Как правильно читать фразу "совершенный вид глагола"?  `[...шэный]` или `[...шоный]`?
Если первое, то почему, ведь второе больше подходит по смыслу?

---

## Уточнение

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/совершенство](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

> со-вер-ше́н-ство. 1. высшая степень, предел какого-либо положительного качества, способности, мастерства. 2. разг. то же, что совершенствование. 3. человек, предмет, лишённый недостатков.

Я не вижу ничего общего с совершенным видом глагола.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Мой первый друг, мой друг **бесценный**! И я судьбу благословил, Когда мой двор **уединенный**, Печальным снегом **занесенный**, Твой колокольчик огласил (А.С. Пушкин). Написано 13 декабря 1826 г.

**Обратим внимание на фонетику причастий.** Это поэзия, высокий стиль, произношение Ё здесь не приветствуется.

**Из истории буквы Ё**. Буква Ё  была создана для обозначения мягкого варианта ударного звука О, который  появился  в результате окончательного закрепления в языке особого фонетического чередования гласных звуков, например: **село – сёла, ледяной – лёд** (раньше говорили **ледяной – лед**).

Возникнув **в разговорной речи**, новое произношение во второй половине XVIII века стало активно проникать в литературный язык. В жанрах высокого стиля, например в трагедии, оно  долгое время считалось **недопустимым**, дольше других чтение Е сохраняется и в философской лирике. Но постепенно вариативность исчезает, мягкий ударный звук О окончательно **закрепляется** в языке.

А когда появилось название видов?  **Это Востоков А.Х. "Русская грамматика" 1831 год.**  Вряд ли "простонародное" Ё могло тогда звучать в лингвистической науке. Поэтому можно сделать вывод: совершенный вид – **это традиция произношения причастия "совершённый" со значением "законченный"**

Также можно отметить, что **нет особого противостояния между причастием "совершённый" и прилагательным "совершенный",** выражающим высшую степень какого-либо положительного качества: совершенство творения предполагает и его законченность тоже.

СПРАВОЧНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ

1) Обсуждение названии видов глагола не является новым, к примеру, вот материал по той же теме [Соверше(ё?)нный вид глагола](http://stcreserv.narod.ru/rusling/ryjaya2.html)

**В XVII-XVIII вв. лингвистика лишь начала разбираться с классификацией глаголов.** По черновикам [5] видно, как долго и постепенно М.В. Ломоносов устанавливал **число и названия видов.** Но труд его не пропал даром: именно его классификация обнажила проблему, сделала очевидной существование дополнительной категории, выделением которой и занялись исследователи с самого начала XIX в.

В литературном произношении XVII-XVIII вв. были сильны церковно-славянские традиции, где звук ё заменялся на е. Поэтому у меня есть сильное подозрение, что слова типа "совершённый", "уединённый" произносились как "совершЕнный", "уединЕнный" (по аналогии с **"житие", "твое"**). Соответственно и писалось: **"совершеннаго вида"**. Если это так, тогда **исторически правильно "совершенный"**, а по смыслу – **"совершённый"**.

2) **Еще об истории изучения видов глагола:**

Категория вида в русском языке оформилась сравнительно поздно (в конце XVI — начале XVII в.), и уже в **XVII в**. она нашла отражение в грамматиках М. Смотрицкого и Ю. Крижанича.

Категория вида, пришедшая на смену богатой системе русских времен, в трудах ряда ученых (Н.И. Греча, А.Х. Востокова и др.) не была четко отграничена от категории времени. **А.Х. Востоков в «Русской грамматике» выделил три вида: неокончательный (несовершенный), совершенный и многократный.** Кроме трех видов он выделил восемь форм времени. Разграничить категории вида и времени ему не удалось.

Comment: Шаронушка, возьми на себя Ингу - она там пропадает. Пиши мне: linaglat@mail.ru

Answer (score 4):

Да, речь идет о **совершённом** действии, но читается соверш**е**нный (вид).
Терминология сложилось давно, нет смысла её менять.

По сути совершенный и совершённый - одно и тоже слово с разделившимися значениями. С той разницей, что первое имеет значение скорее прилагательного, второе - причастия. Слово "совершенство", "совершенность" точно так же восходит к понятию совершить (закончить) что-либо. Нет смысла противопоставлять одно другому.

В общем-то тут и добавить нечего. Ну может то, что в научном стиле использование Ё на месте исторического Е вообще сильно запаздывало по отношению к бытовому. Поэтому удивительно скорее то, что из известных примеров с подобным разделением - этот едва ли не единственный.

Посмотрела другие ответы... Там много есть интересного и правильного, но всё больше - не по теме. На вопрос, "почему" они не отвечают. Впрочем, на такие вопросы вообще очень трудно отвечать, когда речь идет о традиции. Но главное, надеюсь, понятно. *Семантика отвечает именно понятию "совершённый", но закрепилось его историческое произношение "совершенный" (без Ё)*.

Comment: `нет смысла её менять` Я не согласен - ведь заставляют детей это учить. Среди тех кто учат, есть такие, кто может зазубрить, что угодно, а есть, кто чтобы запомнить, должен понять почему так.

Comment: @3per Ну, если бы вся терминология менялась исключительно в угоду простоте изучения... Иногда это происходит, но обычно под влиянием изменения самого объекта изучения или подходов.  Вот, например, "местный" падеж стал "предложным", поскольку утратилось представление о его исторической семантике. Но все остальные падежи сохранили названия. А чем вот объясняется название "винительный" или "творительный", вряд ли кто из "детей" ответит внятно. Если это дитя, конечно, не в курсе латинских названий, давших начало и русским их аналогам.

Answer (score 3):

Я уже писала в комментарии об уникальности термина для обозначения грамматической категории. Вот подтверждение из разных(!)словарей:

Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.

совершенный
1. прил.
1) Отличающийся совершенством; безукоризненный, превосходный.
2) а) Полный, абсолютный.
б) Настоящий, подлинный, истинный.
2. прил.
Выражающий ограниченность действия во времени: законченность, результативность, 
начало и т.п. **(о виде как грамматической категории глагола)**.

С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.

совершенный, -ая, -ое; -енен, -енна.
1. Являющийся совершенством,
превосходный. Совершенное творение. Совершенная красота.
2. Полный,
несомненный. Совершенная правда. С. нахал.
3. совершенно, нареч. Полностью,
в полной мере. Совершенно справедливый. Совершенно верно. Совершенно
секретно. II сущ. совершенность, -и, ж. (к 1 знач.).

---

2. : совершенный вид - **в грамматике: категория глагола,**
   выражающая ограниченность протекания действия по отношению к пределу,
   целостность действия (напр. законченность действия, его начало или
   завершение, результативность,один из моментов действия); противоп.
   несовершенный вид.

Совершенный

соверше́нный
прил., употр. сравн. часто
Морфология: соверше́нен, соверше́нна, соверше́нно, соверше́нны; соверше́ннее
1. Совершенным называют человека, предмет, устройство и т. п., которые не имеют недостатков, изъянов и поэтому считаются лучшими.
Совершенная красота, личность. | Совершенное творение. | Вы всегда были для меня самой совершенной из женщин. | Самая совершенная система, техника, технология.

2. Совершенным называют то, что выражено, проявлено в самой большой степени и является очевидным.
   Совершенное сходство. | Совершенная правда. | Совершенное равнодушие, одиночество.
3. **Совершенной формой** глагола называют грамматическую категорию, которая привносит значение законченности, результативности действия, движения.
   Толковый словарь русского языка Дмитриева Д. В. Дмитриев. 2003

Answer (score 1):

Совершенный вид глагола [səvʲɪr'ʂenɨ̞j] - это категория, обозначающая ограниченное пределом действие в любой момент его осуществления, время такого глагола может быть и будущим. Т.е. действие не обязательно будет "совершённым".

Comment: подскажите, существуют еще варианты применения этого эпитета к другим словам с таким же смыслом? Или это уникальный случай, когда  со словом вид (глагола) один смысл, а со всеми другими - иной?

Comment: "Совершенство" в дискурсе - как правило, нечто "завершенное". Поэтому свою семантику оно сохраняет и в словосочетании "совершенный вид глагола", если вы об этом. Так что никакой уникальности здесь нет.

Comment: Посмотрите уточнение в вопросе, вы действительно считаете, что это одинаковые по смыслу значения?

Comment: Практически идентичные в контексте. А вам предлагаю подумать о прилагательном "совершенный" в значении "абсолютный", "тотальный". Например: "Это же совершенная чушь!"

Comment: Совершенный вид --термин уникален для обозначения грамматической категории, в современном языке в этом значении с другими существительными не употребляется.

Comment: "В этом значении" - это в каком?

Comment: Paranoid, что тотального в форме глагола?

Comment: О видах глагола как о тотальных речи не идет. Я только лишь указываю на широту концептосферы прилагательного "совершенный")

Comment: Ну почему же не будет: "Он придёт" - говорится о завершённости действия в будущем