# Вопрос по фонетике

Tags: фонетика

Здравствуйте. У меня следующий вопрос.

Еще со школы нас обучали тому, что глаголы бывают "совершенного" и "несовершенного" вида. И все 24 года я называл эти глаголы как [савиршэ'н:ый] и [несавиршэ'н:ый].

Но недавно задумался над тем, что логичнее было бы называть их [савиршо'н:ый] и [несавиршо'н:ый].

Подскажите, как правильно?
И как правильно определить произношение написанного слова "совершенный"?
[савирше'н:ый] и [савиршо'н:ый] имеют же разные значения, но пишутся одинаково...

Answer (score 1):

Повтор вопроса: [Совершенный вид глагола или совершённый?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427156/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Что касается произношения, то у  слова **"совершенный"** нет особых правил: гласные звуки  редуцируются в соответствии с общими правилами редукции в предударных и заударных позициях.

Comment: Пожалуйста, голосуйте за закрытие повторных вопросов.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "закрыть", после нажатия откроется окно, где нужно выбрать причину. Также это можно сделать с помощью кнопки "тревога".

Comment: Нет кнопки "закрыть", пришлось воспользоваться кнопкой "тревога".