# В чём совершенство завершённых действий?

Tags: этимология, глаголы, аспектология

Почему *заверш**ё**нные* действия передаются *соверш**е**нным* видом глагола?

Ведь действие *завершено́*, но никак не *соверше́нно*. То есть логично было бы называть вид *соверш**ё**нным* («ё» вместо «е»).

Гипотеза о [написании «е» вместо «ё»](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/) несостоятельна, потому что английское (*perfect tense*) и латинское (*perfectum*) понятия тоже обозначают совершенство.

Comment: Совершенный вид не всегда обозначает завершенные действия. Так, например, глагол "заснул" значит "*начал* спать". Добавлю лишь, что дать универсальное определение понятию вида — одна из важнейших задач аспектологии.

Comment: Английское грамматическое понятие __perfect tense__ точно так же означает **не** "совершенство" (perfectness), а "**завершённость**" действия, выражаемого глагольной формой (a tense of verbs used in describing action that has been **completed**). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfect+tense 
Родственные связи слов "совершенный" и "совершённый" подробно рассмотрены здесь:

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427156/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: @Alex_ander, по приведённой ссылке говорится о простом использовании «е» вместо «ё». Я указал в вопросе, почему не согласен с этой гипотезой.

Comment: @Arhad "Несогласие" несостоятельно. Вы базируетесь исключительно на некоей аналогии (лодно понимаемой, причем) с английским, в то время как исторические источники свидетельствуют, что сам термин в русском закрепился именно как "совершённый"  -  в тогдашнем произношении, английского там и рядом не лежало. Более того, совершённый и совершенный - это исторически вообще одно слово с разделившимися значениями    значениями; *правда это прямого отношения к грамматическому термину не имеет, но показательно, насколько надо аккуратным быть при выведении всяческих аналогий с иностранными языками*

Comment: По поводу "завершенных" действий вам уже тоже сказали, хотя это тоже довольно косвенное отношение к вопросу имеет, а вот что касается английского, то трудно не согласиться, что "perfect" в нем термин весьма многозначный, но уж никак не означающий просто "завершенный". Но это совсем уже из другой оперы.

Comment: @Morkovkin, спасибо за разъяснение. Стоит ли закрывать этот вопрос как дубликат?

Comment: Не думаю, что надо закрывать. Но это пускай модераторы решают. Я вижу в вопросе нечто новое - в части соотнесения с английским, только пожтому и дал развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, всё, что тут нужно сказать, сказано в комментариях.

"Совершенный" и "совершённый" - слова родственные, разделившиеся по смыслу, поэтому не удивительно, что они иногда путаются в связи с появлением в русской фонетике в определенных местах звука, обозначаемого буквой Ё на месте исторического Э (орфографического Е).

Появление некой аналогии с английским легко объясняется тем, что в английском наблюдается та же самая многозначность термина perfect - это не только прекрасный, но и совершенный - причем не только в грамматическом смысле. Видимо, понятие совершенности (эстетической) просто перекликалось с понятием законченности далеко не только в русском менталитете.

Что касается самого термина, то как уже и было сказано, он попал и в русский, и в английский из латинского, поэтому и сохранил кажущееся многозначие.

Маленькое замечание только по поводу термина "калька". Ну думаю, что с учетом всего сказанного, термин "калька" (переводческая) уместен. Это обычный перевод исходно многозначного термина.

Для сравнения. Термин "корень" в грамматике был заимствован из латинского, где им обозначали корень растения, а грамматисты перенесли его и на корень слова. Вот эта искусственность названия, перенесенная на другой язык, может с полным правом называться "калькой". У нас в отношении "совершенного вида" подобной искусственности не проявилось, это просто заимствование перевода  многозначного термина, что само по себе не может являться "калькой". Но это просто к слову, по сути вопроса ничего нового не добавляет.

Comment: Да, запутался в терминах, спасибо )